# Questions about ax.annotate

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a question about these two lines. I don't completely understand it.

The `%` and this `p.get_width(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width()/ 2., p.get_y( ))`

What exactly is it doing ?
And is there a way to remove special values like 0. So that all numbers are shown except the 0? Or to exchange the numbers with names?

```
for p in ax.patches:                  
    ax.annotate(("%1.f") % p.get_width(), (p.get_x() + p.get_width()/ 2., p.get_y( )), fontsize = 2, xytext=(-3, 2),textcoords='offset pixels')
```

Comment: For `%`: see https://pyformat.info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The annotate function add a text to some feature of your plot (https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html). In your case, the annotate function takes the following arguments:

a) The text to be written

```
("%1.f") % p.get_width()
```

This is the complicated part. The % is used to format string. In your case, the % will be replaced by the value of p.get_width(). The 1.f specifies the formatting (a float with one number after the comma). So, if the result of p.get_width() is 1.23445, the result will be the string "1.2". You can change this number with a name without problem. To avoid the value zero, I would make a check in the lines above.

b) The coordinates of the feature to be annotated

```
(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/ 2., p.get_y( ))
```

This is just two floats representing the x coordinate and the y coordinate in the form (x,y)

c) the fontsize of the annotation

```
fontsize = 2
```

d) The coordinates where to write the annotation

```
 xytext=(-3, 2)
```

e) Other arguments

```
textcoords='offset pixels'
```

Comment: *"a float with one number after the comma"*. No, that would be `.1f`